# HTTP response is always empty

Tags: http, go, import, parameters

How do I pass http.ResponseWriter in a parameter?
I'm coming from nodejs and would really like to learn Go.

Here is the main file:

```
import (
    "net/http" 
    "./libs/database"
)

func bla (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   go database.AddFriend("bob", w) 
}
```

Here is database file:

```
import (
    "net/http"
)

 func AddFriend (friendName string, w http.ResponseWriter){
    fmt.Println(friendName)
    w.Write([]byte("Yoooooooo"))    
 }
```

Everything works but the w.Write returns nothing to my ajax post.
I'm keep thinking its like nodejs where I can pass an
object then use it. I know its probably something simple but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: A better approach for your problem would be to have `AddFriend` return a success or error and evaluate that in your handler routine and respond appropriately to the client. Passing the responseWriter around for no reason creates unnecessary coupling for no reward.

Comment: TommyF, you are right. I'm still figuring things out. I should probably get some books on design principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `database.AddFriend` in a goroutine. This is most likely the cause of your problem. By using a goroutine, your connection is closed and response sent, before the output is written to the HTTP response.

```
func bla (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   database.AddFriend("bob", w) 
}
```

Comment: I see. But what if a 10000 users activate func bla at the same time, wouldn't that cause a delay cause everything is synchronous and that a goroutine makes it asycn like a callback function in nodejs?

Comment: The `http` package already handles every request in a separate goroutine.

Comment: Forget everything you're used to in nodejs and learn Go from fundamentals, not as it compares to NodeJS. Go has none of the train wreck of concurrency problems that Node has.